# How to join string with list with python?

Tags: python

For example:
we have a prefix string 'host' 
We have a list like [01,02,03].

I want to get a string like :

```
"host01, host02, host03"
```

I know there is a lot of ways to get the result. But I am expecting something more simple, like one API etc..

Is there such thing?

Comment: `', '.join('host{0:02d}'.format(s) for s in [1, 2, 3])`. And btw. `[01,02,03]` is valid list of 3 octal numbers but it's likely it's not what you want (since you'd simply wrote `[1, 2, 3]`). It may be good to clarify what input list is (especially, what are the types in input list).

Comment: It's only a valid `list` of three octal numbers in Python 2. In Python 3, it's a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
', '.join(['host%02d' % n for n in [1,2,3]])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> ', '.join('host' + x for x in ['01', '02', '03'])
'host01, host02, host03'
```

Comment: I think you cheated by quoting the leading zeroes (unless that's what the OP wanted).